# What does "the node of $xy=0$ is deforming into a circle" mean?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

In *Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces* by *Rick Miranda* Problems $\mathrm{III}.2$:

> Convince yourself that the "difference" (topologically speaking) between the locus $xy=t$ and the locus $xy=0$ for small $t$, near the origin, is exactly that the node of $xy=0$ is deforming into a circle. (Remember that this is all happening in $\mathbb C^2\simeq \mathbb R^4$!)

The node of $xy=0$ is a single point $(0,0)$  while $xy=t$ has no singularity, what does *the node of $xy=0$ is deforming into a circle* mean exactly here?

Comment: Miranda wants you to think about what is happening in a small neighborhood of the origin for $t$ small.

Comment: The locus $xy=t$ is a smooth surface in $\mathbb C^2$, while the locus $xy=0$ is a singular surface. Topologically, going from the former to the latter looks like cutting the smooth surface along a circle, contracting the resulting two boundary circles to points, and gluing those points together. It looks like the degeneration of the smooth quadric surface $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = t$ in $\mathbb R^3$ to $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 0$ as $t \to 0$.

Comment: @TabesBridges this looks like an answer to me. Would you care to record it as such below? (Also, why do you keep answering in the comments? I think I've seen 3 of your comment-answers in the past few days and I've wished I could upvote some of them because they're good solutions.)

Comment: @KReiser Haha! Habit, I suppose. And I end up writing more than I initially intended to.

Answer (score 3):

The locus $xy = t$ is a smooth surface in $\mathbb C^2$, while the locus $xy=0$ is a singular surface. Topologically, going from the former to the latter looks like cutting the smooth surface along a circle, contracting the resulting two boundary circles to points, and gluing those points together.

If this is still hard to visualize, keep in mind that it looks like the (more graphic friendly) degeneration of the smooth quadric surface $x^2 + y^2 − z^2 = t$ in $\mathbb R ^3$ to $x^2 + y^2 − z^2 = 0$ as $t \to 0$.

Comment: Actually, there is no need to cut along the circle: Just take the circle in the surface $xt=t$ and collapse it to a point.

Comment: By "along a circle" do you mean along the circle $(x,y) = (re^{i\theta}, \frac{t}{r}e^{-i\theta})$ for some $r>0$?